# What is the point of constraining to a base class?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

What is the difference between these two methods?

```
public void Add<T>(T item) where T : Product

public void Add(Product item)
```

From what I understand, both will accept only arguments that are of type `Product` or derive from it.

Here I've used methods to exemplify the question, but the same goes to classes.

Comment: You can do a lot more things with generic, but I think no need to put example here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first method lets you do things such as `typeof(T)`, which you couldn't do with the non-generic type, since the object itself may be null (since you'd need to invoke `item.GetType()`).

You're also able to dictate the return type (if instead it was not void), like so:

```
public class Butter : Product { }
public class Egg : Product { }
public class Product { }

public T AddGeneric<T>(T item) where T : Product
{
    //Do something
    return item;
}

public Product Add(Product item)
{
    //Do something

    return item;
}

//Even though we know it's going to return an Egg, we still need to cast here
//If we want to treat t as an Egg, rather than as a Product
Product t = Add(new Egg());

//No cast needed
Egg tt = AddGeneric(new Egg());
```

Also note that a generic method will create one method per type at compile time (and at run time when invoking via reflection).

Comment: "we still need to cast here" --- what does it actually mean? https://dotnetfiddle.net/KfxXLB

Comment: @zerkms I meant that if we wanted `t` to be an `Egg` rather than `Product`, you would need to cast it. I've edited to make that more clear

Answer (score 2):

Both are alike in that they can do anything to `item` that can be done on a `Product`.

The former though can also do things with a type related to the type of `T`. If `T` was type `PremiumProduct` then it could add `item` to a `List<PremiumProduct>` while the other cannot because being a `Product` does not suffice for that.